# Servo motor rotates back to 0 after reaching destination

Tags: servo

I am using a XMG-996R servo motor. It is controlled by and Arduino Uno board. The problem is when I tell it to go to a certain angle, it will rotate to the desired position but then return to 0. The motor keeps rotating back and forth between the destination and 0 degrees. I tried this with different servos and they all do the same.

I am using 3 AA batteries as an external power supply. I have also tried using 4 AA batteries or a 9V battery. The same thing happens no matter the power supply.

My control wire is connected to the Arduino, positive is connected to the external power source. The negative is connected to the ground of the power source and the ground of the Arduino.

This is my code:

```
include <Servo.h>

Servo servo;

void setup(){
   servo.attach(9);
   servo.write(90);
}

void loop(){

}
```

I have also tried putting the write() into loop as well as putting `servo.write()` before `servo.attach()`. neither of these methods made a difference.

What can I do to make the servo rotate to the given degree and stay at that degree? Thanks.

Comment: This belongs in an Arduino forum, but I think you need to keep calling write to constantly send pulses to it. Move write into the main.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. the same thing happened. I increasing the amps. This fixed part of the problem. Now the servo rotates past the target, to the machine limit, back to the target degree and stops.

Comment: I put a ceramic capacitor on the motor, now it works fine.